# How to install bazel for aarch64 architecture

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, bazel, arm64

I am using Linux aarch64 architecture machine with Ubuntu use miniconda3 to install virtual environment.

At first I install tensorflow using conda but when I run the script, I got `Illegal instruction (core dump).`

Therefore,
I try to install bazel for tensorflow according to the below url.
http://zhiyisun.github.io/2017/02/15/Running-Google-Machine-Learning-Library-Tensorflow-On-ARM-64-bit-Platform.html

But I am stuck in the step of `modify bazel source file to compatible with aarch64`

```
diff --git a/scripts/bootstrap/buildenv.sh b/scripts/bootstrap/buildenv.sh
index 502f2c1..a2ab4dc 100755
--- a/scripts/bootstrap/buildenv.sh
+++ b/scripts/bootstrap/buildenv.sh
@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@ PLATFORM="$(uname -s | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')"

 MACHINE_TYPE="$(uname -m)"
 MACHINE_IS_64BIT='no'
-if [ "${MACHINE_TYPE}" = 'amd64' -o "${MACHINE_TYPE}" = 'x86_64' -o "${MACHINE_TYPE}" = 's390x' ]; then
+if [ "${MACHINE_TYPE}" = 'amd64' -o "${MACHINE_TYPE}" = 'x86_64' -o "${MACHINE_TYPE}" = 's390x'  -o "${MACHINE_TYPE}" = 'aarch64' ]; then
   MACHINE_IS_64BIT='yes'
 fi

diff --git a/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/config/BuildConfiguration.java b/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/config/BuildConfiguration.jav
a
index 553c88c..90c8392 100755
--- a/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/config/BuildConfiguration.java
+++ b/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/config/BuildConfiguration.java
@@ -406,6 +406,8 @@ public final class BuildConfiguration {
                 return "arm";
               case S390X:
                 return "s390x";
+             case AARCH64:
+               return "aarch64";
               default:
                 return "unknown";
             }
diff --git a/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/util/CPU.java b/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/util/CPU.java
index 7a85c29..e5f3eae 100755
--- a/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/util/CPU.java
+++ b/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/util/CPU.java
@@ -26,6 +26,7 @@ public enum CPU {
   X86_64("x86_64", ImmutableSet.of("amd64", "x86_64", "x64")),
   PPC("ppc", ImmutableSet.of("ppc", "ppc64", "ppc64le")),
   ARM("arm", ImmutableSet.of("arm", "armv7l")),
+  AARCH64("aarch64", ImmutableSet.of("aarch64")),
   S390X("s390x", ImmutableSet.of("s390x", "s390")),
   UNKNOWN("unknown", ImmutableSet.<String>of());
 
diff --git a/third_party/BUILD b/third_party/BUILD
index 9cd2fac..f1cd14c 100755
--- a/third_party/BUILD
+++ b/third_party/BUILD
@@ -583,6 +583,11 @@ config_setting(
 )

 config_setting(
+    name = "aarch64",
+    values = {"host_cpu": "aarch64"},
+)
+
+config_setting(
     name = "freebsd",
     values = {"host_cpu": "freebsd"},
 )
diff --git a/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl b/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl
index 0ae4483..975908b 100755
--- a/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl
+++ b/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl
@@ -142,8 +142,10 @@ def _get_cpu_value(repository_ctx):
   result = repository_ctx.execute(["uname", "-m"])
   if result.stdout.strip() in ["power", "ppc64le", "ppc"]:
     return "ppc"
-  if result.stdout.strip() in ["arm", "armv7l", "aarch64"]:
+  if result.stdout.strip() in ["arm", "armv7l"]:
     return "arm"
+  if result.stdout.strip() in ["aarch64"]:
+    return "aarch64"
   return "k8" if result.stdout.strip() in ["amd64", "x86_64", "x64"] else "piii"
```

I cannot find the source file in the folder that I unzip the bazel-0.4.4-dist.zip
But I don't know where can I find the bazel source file to modify so that it will compatible with aarch64? May I know should I copy all the below script to the bazel source file? May I know why --- a/src/main/java/.... line is highlighted with red and ++++ b/src/main/java/.... line is highlighted with green? Does it mean all the red lines are needed to delete and replace with the green highlighted lines?

After this steps, may I know how can I compile the Bazel? Do you know any command to compile the Bazel?

May I know ./compile.sh step should execute only after finished compiling the Bazel?
$ ./compile.sh

Moreover, I installed miniconda3 in the linux (the folder of miniconda3 is /home/su/miniconda3/) and  created a new virtual environment in the miniconda3.
The subfolders inside the miniconda3 are :

LICENSE.txt
compiler_compat
etc
python-package
aarch64-conda-linux-gnu
conda-meta
include
share
aarch64-conda_cos7-linux-gnu
condabin
lib
shell
bin
envs
pkgs
ssl

For my case after finishing the step ./compile.sh , may I know to which path should I copy the /output/bazel if my virtual environment is created in miniconda3 instead of the local? I don't know can I use /usr/local/bin/ folder if my virtual environment is in miniconda3.
#Copy bazel to $PATH
$ sudo cp output/bazel /usr/local/bin/
When I checked the bazel-0.4.4 folder, there is no "output/bazel" folder. May I know where can I find the /output/bazel folder to copy bazel to $PATH?

May I  know in which folder should I build the pip package if my virtual environment is created in miniconda3? Can I use the same folder /tmp/tensorflow_pkg  or should I change the location of the folder?
#Build pip package
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

Comment: Some references [#1](https://medium.com/@m7807031/how-to-install-tensorflow-in-different-os-languane-framework-66b3beaa1b3d),  [#2](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/ai-and-ml-blog/posts/building-bazel-and-tensorflow-2-x-on-aarch64)

Comment: @Susan, kindly follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://bazel.build/install/ubuntu) to install Bazel, and refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) for tensorflow installation. Thank you!